# Call a managed C# library with P/invoke without Assembly.Load or similar

Tags: c#, .net-core, pinvoke, .net-assembly, corert

I've been around for days looking for this but all I find is how to call **unmanaged** libraries from C# using P/Invoke. I need to do it differently: I'm looking to use P/Invoke to call a **managed** assembly from another one (or use something else, **avoiding** to call `Assembly.Load`, `Assembly.LoadFrom`, etc.) basically due to a CoreRT/NativeAOT limitation (see [here](https://github.com/dotnet/runtimelab/issues/155)).

Basically, the idea of using CoreRT/NativeAOT is due to the native executable generation, which would improve a bit my app's security as common decompilers won't work with it (except IDA and a clever dev with ASM knowledge, but they're harder to come by). Considering that CoreRT/NativeAOT cannot ([it can](https://github.com/dotnet/corert/pull/6182), but the .NET team just doesn't want to right now...) load external assemblies using any of the .NET Interop methods (`Assembly.Load`, `Assembly.LoadFrom`, etc.) but it can use `DllImport`, I'd like to call an external assembly that I don't really care much if it's decompiled or not without using any of those Assembly loading methods.

Yeah, I know I could write a wrapper or something with CoreRT itself to generate a native lib and call it with P/Invoke from the app, but in the case of Entity Framework which doesn't compile due to `Reflection.Emit`, it's not a possibility.

The ideal solution here would be to know **how to call any .NET assembly (DLL) from another C# app/assembly WITHOUT using Assembly.Load/LoadFrom/LoadFromStream/etc. using other methods, be either P/Invoke (can it?) or other ones.**

Comment: Your question doesn't have any code and mostly look like as discussion in one of MS github repositories

Comment: Not sure if it helps: .NET 5 recently announced something about native exports: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-net-5-0/#native-exports

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski it does NOT have to have any code, AFAIK. What kind of code can I show when there's no known way (that I know of) to do what I want to do? MS's repos don't allow questions on their github because "they don't provide tech support there" and besides, when I ask that, I get a link to the issue I just put where it says they won't support that yet. I refuse to accept such a canned answer because I'm sure that what I want to achieve is possible. I just don't know how, and that's why I'm asking here.

Comment: @ChristianHeld thanks a lot for that link, I've been working with .NET 5 and been adapting to the latest changes. I think that Native Exports could be what I'm looking for. I'll do a test and if it works I'll answer my own question with some code to show. Thank you!

Comment: @ChristianHeld I'd like to award you the answer, as your suggestion did work. I have some code to show, but I wouldn't like to answer it myself as you really did help me, and I'd like to set up an example here for the community where just downvoting a question should not be the norm. Would you like to chat about it? I dunno how to initiate a chat here, but see if you can message me somehow and I'll set up the code for you to share so I can mark it as answer. Thanks! (Or maybe you can make your comment an answer, and I'll update the OP)

Comment: @DARKGuy I am glad that my comment pointed you towards the solution, that's enough reward for me :). It is you how figured out how it works, so please post your solution as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUTION**

Thanks to @ChristianHeld for his suggestion to use .NET 5.0's Native Exports (plus also thanks to Aaron Robinson for his code. I got it working this way:

.csproj:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
    ADD THIS -> <EnableDynamicLoading>true</EnableDynamicLoading>
    ADD THIS -> <DnneAddGeneratedBinaryToProject>true</DnneAddGeneratedBinaryToProject>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    ADD THIS -> <PackageReference Include="DNNE" Version="1.*" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Library .NET Code (stripped):

```
[UnmanagedCallersOnlyAttribute]
public static void Init()
{
    // ... Some code here...
}
```

Caller .NET Code (sample):

```
class Program
{
    const string LIBNAME = @"LibraryNE.dll";
    [DllImport(LIBNAME)] public static extern void Init();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Init();
    }
}
```

**IMPORTANT:** When running with VSCode (F5) it may say something like this:

`Failed to initialize context for config: C:\Project\Library.runtimeconfig.json. Error code: 0x80008092`

Disregard this, as it seems to happen because VSCode debugs the app with `dotnet.exe`, disregarding each assembly's runtimeconfig.json (somehow it throws `LibHostInvalidArgs`. No idea why).

If you execute your app's .EXE directly, it will work (just used it with a CoreRT/NativeAOT-generated binary). The solution to this is to edit your `launch.json` file and change `.dll` with `.exe` in `configurations -> program`.

Also, remember to copy the .NET dll as well. It seems that when you publish, only the native library (suffixed with NE) is copied, but it won't work by itself as it's just a wrapper. It needs the real .NET dll to be in the same folder as well.

The debugging experience isn't so great, as when you debug the method it seems to use a different, non-existing source file so the line numbers when you step through don't match. It's debuggable, but you'll be doing so against ghost/offset lines.